# Scanner not reading content from file

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I am trying to write the number 0 to a file called amountSessions the first time it is created as you can see in the if statement below the comment "On the first run" which works so far, but later on in the program (at the end of the writeToFile method) below the comment "Increment number each run" I want to increment the 0 I discussed earlier by 1 each time the program runs. Unfortunetly when I do compile and run the program I am given the following error. Why is this? Thank you very much everybody!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at math_program.fileWriting.getInt(fileWriting.java:62)
at math_program.fileWriting.writeToFile(fileWriting.java:41)

//Test

package testing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Kappa
{
    String numberFilePath = "/Users/john/Desktop/numProblems.txt";
    String sessionFilePath = "/Users/john/Desktop/amountSessions.txt";
    File testFile = new File(numberFilePath);
    File amountSessions = new File(sessionFilePath); 

    public void writeToFile() throws IOException
    {

        //On the first run
        if(!testFile.exists())
        {
            testFile.createNewFile();
        } else if(!amountSessions.exists())
        {
            amountSessions.createNewFile();
            FileWriter sessionWriter = new FileWriter(amountSessions);
            sessionWriter.write("0");
            sessionWriter.close();
        }

        FileWriter durationWriter = new FileWriter(testFile);
        FileWriter sessionWriter = new FileWriter(amountSessions);

        //Write Duration
        String ans = prompt();
        durationWriter.write(ans);
        durationWriter.close();

        //Increment number each run
        sessionWriter.write(getInt());
        sessionWriter.close();

        System.exit(0); 
    }

    public void grab() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner numProblemsReader = new Scanner(new File("/Users/john/Desktop/numProblems.txt"));
        Scanner numSessionReader = new Scanner(new File("/Users/john/Desktop/amountSessions.txt"));
        int number = numProblemsReader.nextInt();
        int numSessions = (numSessionReader.nextInt() + 1);

        System.out.println("The number read from the file is: " + number);
        File replaceFile = new File("/Users/john/Desktop/session" + numSessions + ".txt");
        testFile.renameTo(replaceFile);
    }

    public String getInt() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner numSessionReader = new Scanner(new File("/Users/john/Desktop/amountSessions.txt"));
        int numSessions = ((numSessionReader.nextInt()) + 1);
        String newNum = Integer.toString(numSessions);
        return newNum;
    }

    public String prompt()
    {
        String ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the new amount of problems per training session (with number in minutes):");                        

        while(!ans.matches("[0-9]+"))
        {
            ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please re-enter the new amount of problems per training session (with number in minutes):" ); 
        }    

        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please dont open read/write same file 2 times

Comment: You're trying to read and write from/to the same file at the same time. Don't. Read everything first, then write.

Comment: How would I fix this though? Should I call a method with all the writing to the files? How would I fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
} else if(!amountSessions.exists())
```

To

```
}
if(!amountSessions.exists())
```

Otherwise only the first file will be created if neither exist.

Comment: It fixes the case of not having either file but expecting that they should both exist.

Comment: No it doesn't fix anything actually because even with the else if it still created both files.

Comment: I'd love to know how it did that, since the only one of those conditional blocks can execute. Are you sure that nothing else is creating one or both of the files?

Comment: I have no clue how, don't get me wrong I am not trying to diss you or anything but I swear when I compile the code thats what it gives me.

Comment: Might it not be worth trying to work out why both files exist? If something else is creating that file, it might be writing something other than an int to the file (E.g. nothing or a String). Don't worry, I'm not offended, I'd just advise fixing this bug as well.